# iPhone: Modal View Controller Leaking Memory

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a modalViewController. After I dismiss the modal view controller with:

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

.. the view is still in memory. How do I dismiss it such that it will use memory?

Thanks.

Comment: only an object with retain count = 1 calls its dealloc when release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you present your modal view controller, you need to release it.

Comment: Of course. Before I present the modalViewController, I allocate at first a UINavigationController and UIViewController, add the UIViewController to the UINavigationController as rootViewController, afterwards I present the modalViewController and release both UINavigationController and UIViewController. What else to do??

Comment: Make sure that all of these are released from your code.  Having a retain on any of them will hold your controller.  Check for other values that you may have passed in and not released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I'm only temporarily retaining the ViewController until I call presentModalViewController, then release the alloc. But after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, I never get the ViewController's dealloc.

If I add a self-release from the ViewController, then I get this after control returns to the event loop:

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
objc_msgSend

Comment: only an object with retain count = 1 calls its dealloc when release.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. I have a NavigationController that I present modally, and as rootController of this NavigationController I have simple ViewController object. The rare situation is, when I run my app against Instruments using Allocations and after dismissing the modalController, in this case the NavigationController, the NavigationController goes away but the rootController remains in memory and memory grows and grows. (note: Leak in Instruments does not show any leak and the app was running on the device not the simulator).

Comment: is you release the view controller after it added as rootviewcontroller of navigation bar? and put all the IB Objects to nil in viewDidUnload. and still remains your problem. let us allow to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

when you are presenting a modal view controller you will be definitely allocating so there is rule whenever you allocate you need to release it also so please release the view controller which you are presenting in the modalviewcontroller.